# HTML5 Geolocation save to database

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation

I have a simple HTML5 GeoLocation script.

```
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>
```

The question is how can I get `position.coords.latitude` & `position.coords.longitude` and put it in my database?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Explain a bit more? Is it inside a form?

Comment: This is a very low quality question (too broad, lack of any research, asking about a very common problem). You should search the Internet and read some basic information. Topic of saving any data to database, using any language on server-side has been answered and described in details at least million times so far!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a ajax post like this:

```
$.post('recv.php', position.coords)
```

and then have the php put in in the database.

Comment: IMHO the question is very poor (too broad, lack of any research, asking about a very common problem), but your answer isn't much better. To stand SE quality levels and make your answer really valuable, you would have to provide at least an example of suggested `recv.php` file (server-side) code. If someone asks "How to save something to database" and you answer "Write yourself a code that will save this to database" and don't provide any code example then you are making really low quality answer, sorry.